# How to insert value into vector array

Tags: c++, vector, queue

I am trying to create a `std::vector` with a fixed size array that accepts `uint64_t` values, and then push that vector into a `std::queue`. I am able to create the vector with:
`vector<uint64_t[10]> tmp_data(255);` which if I understand correctly is "a vector with 10 arrays of size 255 and accepts uint64_t values"

```c++
int main()
{
    vector<uint64_t[10]> tmp_data(255);
    std::queue<std::vector<uint64_t>> vectQueue;

    // error: request for member ‘insert’ in ‘tmp_data.std::vector<long unsigned int [10]>::operator[](0)’, which is of non-class type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<long unsigned int [10]>, long unsigned int [10]>::value_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int [10]’}
    tmp_data[0].insert(tmp_data.begin(),7); // I want to insert the value "7" in index 0
    tmp_data[1].insert(tmp_data.begin(),6); // 6 in index 1
    tmp_data[2].insert(tmp_data.begin(),5); // 5 in index 2
    tmp_data[2].insert(tmp_data.begin(),4); // 5 in index 2 (so 4,5)

    // then push to queue
    vectQueue.push(tmp_data);
}
```

Comment: The question title says there's an error from `push`, but the error in the code in the question is for `insert`. Is that a typo, or are both calls causing an error?

Comment: Instead of *"a vector with 10 arrays of size 255 and accepts uint64_t values"*, I would write *"a `vector` containing 255 `array`s of 10 `int`s"*

Comment: For your `insert()` logic to make any sense, you would need to use `std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> tmp_data(3);` and `std::queue<std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>>> vectQueue;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually fully descriptive:

a "value" in your queue is a `std::vector<uint64_t>`, but you're trying to insert an integer. That doesn't work - an integer is not a `std::vector<uint64_t>`. It's not quite sure what you meant to do here. Maybe you wanted

```
std::queue<uint64_t, std::vector<uint64_t>> vectQueue;
```

instead? But honestly, you almost never would want a queue with a `std::vector` as underlying container - that's **really** inefficient, because you're constantly copying data back and forth, allocating more often than you should, and not saving anything, since you're still doing at least one memory indirection per lookup, compared to a `std::deque`, which `std::queue` uses by default. The simple

```
std::queue<uint64_t> vectQueue;
```

would make more sense. Did you read [documentation on `std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)?

The more I read your question, the more I've got a feeling you're confused about the data structure you're trying to build here, and I think sitting down and thinking about what actually should be a `vector` and what a `queue`, and reading what these are, would make your life much easier :)